# I would like to access DataTables **cell** with click function in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a laravel 5.4 application I am working on. It contains, off course, some forms where I have input fields next to a search button. When the user clicks on the search button a modal windows appears with a dataTable whose content are fetched from the database.

Now, what I would like to achieve is that once I click on a cell of that table, it picks the specific data in the cell and fetch it to the input field then close the modal window using jquery.

Here is my code.

1. DataTable:

   ```
           $('#mere-table').DataTable({
           processing: false,
           serverSide: true,
           ordering: false,
           ajax:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/nouveau_ne/data_meres',
           columns :[
               {data : 'nnid', name:'t_individus.nnid', className:"NNID_mere"},
               {data : 'nom', name:'t_individus.nom'},
               {data : 'postnom', name:'t_individus.postnom'},
               {data : 'prenom', name:'t_individus.prenom'},
                    ]
           });
   ```
2. JQuery to pick data from a cell and fetch it to the inputfield **NNID_mere**

   ```
             $('#mere-table').DataTable().on('click','.NNID_mere', function(){

                                     alert('ok'+$('.NNID_mere').text());

                                     });
   ```

What I get from this code is after I click on the cell, the alert picks all the data from the column **nnid**. I just want one cell, not the full column but I do not know how to go about this as I am not great in jquery.

How can I achieve this? Your help and tips are appreciated

Comment: Can you make a demo of this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store the dataTable instance in a variable :

```js
var table = $('#mere-table').DataTable({ .. })
```

Then simply

```js
$('#mere-table').on('click','.NNID_mere', function(){
  console.log( table.cell(this).data() )
});
```